# Fast scrolling in Listview doesn't work if it's in ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I was using `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Since they deprecated whole class of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, I had to migrate `ViewPager2`. I could successfully migrated `ViewPager2`, using `FragmentStateAdapter`, and so on.

Everything works fine, connecting `ViewPager2` with `TabLayout` also works smoothly, I can slide `ViewPager2`, and I also can control it via `TabLayout`. But now I can't fast scroll `ListView`, even though I touch cursor to control scrolling, it won't scroll down nor up. Then if I just scroll down/up via touching `ListView` normally, then cursor suddenly moves to listview's current position. Testers reported that in some device, it works only in landscape mode while my emulator and device doesn't work neither on portrait nor landscape.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundPrimary">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/cscollapse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/cstool">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/cstool"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/csbck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        app:borderWidth="0dp"
                        app:elevation="0dp"
                        app:fabSize="mini"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_button"
                        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/cslisttab"
            style="@style/CounterStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="auto"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CounterStyle"
            app:tabTextColor="?attr/UnitinfoName" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/cslistscroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"


        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".CastleList">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/cslistpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/prog"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/load_process"
                android:textColor="?attr/TextPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/prog"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/prog"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prog" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is layout of list screen activity, as you can see, I'm using AppBarLayout with ViewPager2.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/entitylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entitynores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/filter_nores"
        android:textColor="?attr/TextPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what layout `ViewPager2` is using, it's just simple layout which contains one `TextView` and `ListView`. As you can see, fast scroll is activated for `ListView`, also with nest scrolling allowed because it won't scroll in view pager if I disable this.

```kotlin
val tab = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.cslisttab)
val pager = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.cslistpager)

pager.adapter = CsListTab()
pager.offscreenPageLimit = getExistingCastle()

val keys = getExistingPack()

TabLayoutMediator(tab, pager) { t, position ->
    val def = getString(R.string.pack_default) ?: "Default"

    t.text = when(position) {
        0 -> "$def - RC"
        1 -> "$def - EC"
        2 -> "$def - WC"
        3 -> "$def - SC"
        else -> StaticStore.getPackName(keys[position])
    }
}.attach()

if(getExistingCastle() == 1) {
    tab.visibility = View.GONE

    val collapse = findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.cscollapse)

    val param = collapse.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams

    param.scrollFlags = 0

    collapse.layoutParams = param
}

val bck = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.csbck)

bck.setOnClickListener {
    activity.finish()
}
```

Above is code in `OnCreate` method, it lacks some references, but I think you guys will be able to understand what I did, other things aren't that important.

```kotlin
inner class CsListTab : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lc) {
    private val keys = getExistingPack()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return keys.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return CsListPager.newInstance(keys[position])
    }
}
```

This is `FragmentStateAdapter` I made. This one also contains some unexplained/unneeded methods/variables, but I think it can explain what I did.

```kotlin
class CsListPager : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(pid: String) : CsListPager {
            val cs = CsListPager()

            val bundle = Bundle()

            bundle.putString("pid", pid)
            cs.arguments = bundle

            return cs
        }
    }

    private var pid = Identifier.DEF

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val c = context ?: return null

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entity_list_pager, container, false)

        pid = arguments?.getString("pid") ?: Identifier.DEF

        val list = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.entitylist)
        val nores = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.entitynores)

        val p: PackData
        var index = -1

        if(pid.startsWith(Identifier.DEF)) {
            val d = pid.split("-")

            p = UserProfile.getPack(d[0])

            index = if(d.size == 1)
                0
            else
                d[1].toInt()
        } else {
            p = UserProfile.getPack(pid)
        }

        if(p is PackData.DefPack) {
            nores.visibility = View.GONE

            val csList = CastleList.defset().toList()[if(index == -1) 0 else index]

            val names = ArrayList<String>()
            val data = ArrayList<Identifier<CastleImg>>()

            for(i in csList.list.indices) {
                names.add(StaticStore.generateIdName(csList.list[i].id, c))
                data.add(csList.list[i].id)
            }

            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(c, R.layout.list_layout_text, names.toTypedArray())

            list.adapter = adapter

            list.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, posit, _ ->
                if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - StaticStore.cslistClick < StaticStore.INTERVAL)
                    return@OnItemClickListener

                StaticStore.cslistClick = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()

                val intent = Intent(c, ImageViewer::class.java)

                intent.putExtra("Data", JsonEncoder.encode(data[posit]).toString())
                intent.putExtra("Img", ImageViewer.CASTLE)

                c.startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else if(p is PackData.UserPack && p.castles.list.isNotEmpty()) {
            nores.visibility = View.GONE

            val csList = p.castles

            val names = ArrayList<String>()
            val data = ArrayList<Identifier<CastleImg>>()

            for(i in csList.list.indices) {
                names.add(StaticStore.generateIdName(csList.list[i].id, c))
                data.add(csList.list[i].id)
            }

            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(c, R.layout.list_layout_text, names.toTypedArray())

            list.adapter = adapter

            list.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, posit, _ ->
                if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - StaticStore.cslistClick < StaticStore.INTERVAL)
                    return@OnItemClickListener

                StaticStore.cslistClick = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()

                val intent = Intent(c, ImageViewer::class.java)

                intent.putExtra("Data", JsonEncoder.encode(data[posit]).toString())
                intent.putExtra("Img", ImageViewer.CASTLE)

                c.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

I don't think I need to post `Fragment` code too, but just in case I will post it.

I don't know why this is happening. I looked into issue tracker either, but couldn't find good answer from there. I don't know if this is my fault or android `ViewPager2`'s bug

1. Is this because I coded `ViewPager2` incorrectly?
2. If not, can this be bug of `ViewPager2`?
3. If yes for one of 1 or 2, is there any workaround?

Both my emulator and device is Android 11 (API 30), and I'm using Android Studio Canary (Picture below)

[image: Android Studio Version]

Below gif describes the problem I'm having currently

[image: Fast Scrolling Not Working]

EDIT :

I don't know if this can be the hint of this problem, but I noticed that one screen can fast scroll. Fast scroll works only in landscape mode. When I try to fast scroll on portrait mode, this debug message is printed

`D/AbsListView:  in onLayout changed`

But if I try to fast scroll in landscape, such debug message won't be printed, but this message got printed.

`D/DecorView: semSetRoundedCorners: 5`

In portrait mode, I can't see debug message above (which is from `DecorView`) while in landscape mode, I can't see debug message which is from `AbsListView`. The thing is that this screen has different layout file for each orientation. But it's just font size difference, I put same view with same ID in there, so each layout are actually identical each other.

I'm trying to find what difference each layout has for now, I will update question when I found one

Answer (score 1):

```xml
            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/cslistpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Okay, I finally found a workaround. I still don't know why this is happening, and I'm guessing that this is either my fault or bug of `ViewPager2` itself. As you can see, `layout_width` and `layout_height` properties are set as `match_parent`. If any of these are set as `match_parent`, fast scroll won't work. Below is the way to fix fast scroll bug.

```
            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/cslistpager"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Setting `layout_width`, and `layout_height` to `0dp` fixed problem. I noticed that I must not use `match_parent` in `ConstraintLayout` (Even though IDE lets you). I could find this while finding difference between `0dp` and `match_parent`. I still don't know if this is the real cause of problem, but for now, problem solved.